# NSMutableArray of ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I am woundering how I could create an NSMutableArray of viewcontrollers.

Then once I had that array how could I use it in a method that detects left and right UIgesture swipes to animate in and out of view...

this is the method that is picking up my gestures which is just animating between two views, however I would like to animate between as many views that are in the array of view controllers.

```
- (void)swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    //Left swipe
    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [self.detailViewB.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            [self.detailViewA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];

    }
    //Right swipe
    else if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [self.detailViewA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            [self.detailViewB.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        }];

    }
}
```

as a side I have a master view controller that I am loading these viewcontrollers into as subviews... well at least thats the plan..  Im currently doing this with the views...

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53813770/SMPrototypeB.zip

UPDATED:

here is a graphic showing you guys what I am trying to achive.

[image]

Heres the code that got it to load the view from the array.. thank goodness, what a pain.

```
DetailViewController *DVCA = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
DetailViewControllerB *DVCB = [[DetailViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewControllerB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
DetailViewControllerC *DVCC = [[DetailViewControllerC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewControllerC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//Create Array of views
viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DVCA, DVCB, DVCC, nil];



// set detail View as first view 
UIViewController *recordController = [viewArray objectAtIndex:0];
// This was the bit causing me so many issues.
[self.view addSubview:recordController.view];
```

Comment: If your initial view controller is a navigation controller, then the OS gives you the array your looking for, it's the viewControllers property on UINavigationController. That's immutable but you could make a mutable copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am woundering how I could create an NSMutableArray of viewcontrollers.

Same way as you'd create any other array of objects:

1. Create the objects.
2. Put them in the array.

You certainly can do that in your app delegate or root view controller -- whichever object is in charge of all the other view controllers. I'd probably go with having the app delegate manage the view controllers. Then you can set the first responder as the target of the swipe gesture recognizer, and implement the action to switch between view controllers in the app delegate (which is part of the responder chain).

Comment: I have updated my question with a diagram of what I am trying to achieve, the reason I cannot do this stuff in the array is because I want the MainViewController to display the views in the array as subviews..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your project and seeing that your root view controller is in fact a navigation controller, I'm reposting as an answer.

If your initial view controller is a navigation controller, then the OS gives you the array you're looking for, it's the viewControllers property on UINavigationController. That's immutable but you could make a mutable copy of it.

Comment: the reason I want to create a new NSMutableArray of ViewControllers is that I am setting up a swiping feature at this level of the navigation controller.. because at this level of the navigation stack I want to display a bunch of data I cannot do it on one view, so instead of loading more views onto the stack I want the user to be able to swipe between a bunch of views that are in the mutableAreray at this level of the stack.. then once they are done they can go back to doing what ever they want on the stack...

Answer (score 0):

How about using an out of the box UIScrollView to get the same effect?  It supports scrolling in multiple directions, would save you all the overhead of developing a new control, and you wouldn't have to worry about violating any HIG guidelines.

Comment: do you think I am violating HIG guidelines?

Comment: Looks okay to me but I'm not reviewing apps :)  The UIScrollView is pretty flexible, I've used it to horizontally scroll video thumbnails without having to tweak anything.

Comment: Yea I think I would go down that road if I didn't need control over each view that I will be swiping in, as there will be lots of different data that I want to display, from UIWbviews scrollviews and just native Interface controls etc, and having the viewcontroller for each view would help keep everything in order I think..  but cheers for the reccomendation, it might be something I muck round with in the future and test, like I am doing now with the views being stored in the arrays.

Comment: So you could have your app delegate manage loading and switching views.  When the app loads, the delegate would add the default view as a subview and then place a transparent view or layer on top of it to manage the gestures.  That view would communicate with the delegate to swap views underneath it when it received touch events.  That would give you a clean separation of concerns because everything would ONLY talk to the app delegate.  That's how I would build it... if I had to :)

Comment: Cool, I might try that next.. cheers for chatting about it, it always helps bouncing ideas off people.