# Changing Navigation Controller's view on button press

Tags: ios, xcode

I've setup a Navigation Controller which is connected to two View Controllers (B & C). The Navigation Controller is connected to a Container View which is inside a View Controller (A). In this View Controller (A) I also have some buttons which just logs some simple messages to the console.

```
View Controller A
    -> Container -> Navigation Controller
                                  -> View Controller B
                                  -> View Controller C
```

Now how can I change the active View controller (B OR C) inside the Navigation Controller when a button is pressed? I'm fairly new to Xcode and my biggest problem here I think, is that I don't know how to access the different views programmatically.

Comment: Where this button is located - in controller A or B? Why you can not just push new controller into stack? [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerC animated:YES];

Comment: The button is located in View Controller A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this tutorial

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

use navigation controllers array to access view controllers , i think you should check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825853/nsmutablearray-of-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

...

ViewControllerB* vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import viewController which you want to navigate.

ViewController.h Import ViewControllerC

```
#import "ViewControllerC.h"
```

ViewControllerB.m file..

```
 ViewControllerC * gmavc=[[ViewControllerC  alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerC " bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:gmavc animated:YES];
```

Try this code...

Comment: What file is `#import "ViewControllerC.h"` in?